# CakePHP 2.3.0 Form Validation errors not showing up- form fields in different models

Tags: validation, cakephp, formhelper

I am trying to get errors from the Model to show up on form submission. I do not save this data anywhere on the DB, so not using the save method. The problem is that I am unable to see the validation errors set in the Model AnonymousRider. Code follows-
ctp file

```
<?php
    echo $this -> Form -> create(null, array('action' => 'confirmBooking'));

    echo $this -> Form -> input('Name', array('type' => 'text', 'id' => 'name', 'placeholder' => 'Name'));
    echo $this -> Form -> input('AnonymousRider.email', array( 'id' => 'email', 'placeholder' => 'Email'));
    echo $this -> Form -> input('AnonymousRider.phone_number', array( 'type' => 'tel', 'id' => 'number', 'placeholder' => 'Mobile Number'));
    echo $this -> Form -> input('address', array('type' => 'textarea', 'id' => 'pickup-point', 'placeholder' => 'pickup address and landmark details', 'required' => 'true'));
    echo $this -> Form -> input('tnc', array('type' => 'checkbox', 'id' => 'tnc', 'required' => 'true'));

    echo $this->Html->link('Terms and conditions', '/pages/home', array('class' => 'button', 'target' => '_blank'));
    $options = array('label' => 'Book Now', 'class' => 'btn btn-success .btn-large');
    echo $this -> Form -> end($options);
    ?>
```

Following is the model-

```
var $name = 'AnonymousRider';
public $validate = array
    (
        'phone_number' => array('rule' => array('phone', null, 'us'), 'message' => 'valid phone number required'), 
        'email' => array('rule' => 'email', 'message' => 'valid phone number required'), 
    );
```

}?>

I can see that the model rules are generating a required around the HTML. See HTML-

```
<form action="/91/itinerary_requests/confirmBooking" id="ItineraryRequestConfirmBookingForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<div style="display:none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
</div>
<div class="input text">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input name="data[ItineraryRequest][Name]" id="name" placeholder="Name" type="text">
</div>
<div class="input email required">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input name="data[AnonymousRider][email]" id="email" placeholder="Email" maxlength="256" type="email" required="required">
</div>
<div class="input tel required">
    <label for="number">Phone Number</label>
    <input name="data[AnonymousRider][phone_number]" id="number" placeholder="Mobile Number" type="tel" required="required">
</div>
<div class="input textarea">
    <label for="pickup-point">Address</label>       <textarea name="data[ItineraryRequest][address]" id="pickup-point" placeholder="pickup address and landmark details" required="required" cols="30" rows="6"></textarea>
```

Tnc
    Terms and conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can validate your data in your controller

see [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html)

all you have to do is somethin like:

```
if ($this->ModelName->validates()) {
    // it validated logic
} else {
    // didn't validate logic
    $errors = $this->ModelName->validationErrors;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. Also I see that the email validation is done client side throwing the default error - "Please enter an email address". I am trying to make the same thing happen for the telephone number indicating a client side error if we enter a non-number. Any clues on that one? Here is the generated HTML <div class="input tel required"><label for="number">Phone</label><input type="tel" required="required" maxlength="20" placeholder="Mobile Number" id="number" name="data[AnonymousRider][phone]"></div>

Comment: The client side validation has noting to do with cake and is a htmml5 feature. Cake just set the input type and your browser does the rest. I guess there is not a client side telephone validation

Comment: some research brought me to- " Due to inherent variances in phone number formats, the tel input type does not conform to any specific pattern. Rather, browsers treat it as a regular, single-line text input field, the result of which is that no attempt is made by the browser to validate the field. The main advantage to using this type of field then is to optimize the keyboard on mobile devices" http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/whats-new-in-html5-forms-email-url-and-telephone-input-types.html#fbid=dfttbzhasVR

Comment: What to with cakephp1.2 i set $this->set('errors',$this->ModelName->validationErrors); But no error shows in the view.